# Work function of metal and semiconductor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics

Which work function is greater: metal or semiconductor?  and why?

According to me, metal must have lower work function (the minimum energy to remove an electron) than semiconductors.. but reverse is correct.
Why?

Comment: Why must that be the case? Perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: Because it's easier to grab an electron from metals.. isn't it ?

Comment: Did you look on the Web for work function values?

Comment: The statement is written in my book...

Comment: @AjitKumar !  
Try using Bohr's model for the sake of simplified understanding.Work function will be very close to the energy in the outermost orbit( in reality, work function is measured from Fermi level, but ignore that). So, if you give the energy equal to the energy in the outermost orbit, the electron will get freed.
Now, when comparing, values will really depend upon the metal and semiconductor in question( what's their outermost orbit number ?).

Comment: But , if you are talking about metal schottky diodes, generally metals like molybdenum, platinum, chromium, tungsten, gold and silver are used, all of them with really high atomic number and high number of shells. You can compare their outermost shell number in Bohr's model with 3 (for Silicon ).